# Rails polymorphic comments ajax - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used this tutorial for making polymorphic comments

https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations

It works fine but when I set remote true to my comments form I got 505 error(the new comment is not appended to the list) when trying to add a new comment.

But when I reload the page the new comment appears in the list.

**What can be wrong here?**

I got this files in views/comments folder:

[image]

**create.js**

```
<% unless @comment.errors.any? %>
$("ul.comments").append('<%= j render "comments/comment" %>')
$("#new_comment")[0].reset();
<% end %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([commentable, Comment.new], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, label: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comment was successfully added."}
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
  <li class="comment">
    <b><%= comment.user.try(:username) %>:</b>
    <%= comment.body%>
  </li>
```

console

[image]

**UP**

I got this routes for post

```
  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments, module: :posts
  end
```

+
controllers/posts/comments_controller

```
class Posts::CommentsController < CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable

  private
  def set_commentable
    @commentable = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

The folder structure looks almost the same as here
https://github.com/excid3/gorails-episode-36/tree/master/app/controllers

the response tab shows this

```
undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x007f993d3c5450>:0x007f99450a6190>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/comments/create.js.erb
```

and when I replace

<%= j render @comment %> with some text it appends to the list on submit

ok the problem is with _comment.html erb

Comment: what is exactly the error ? HTTP 505 seems really odd

Comment: what is `@commentable` in your create action? do you define it somewhere?

Comment: To easily debug this, in your JavaScript console, click the Network tab. Then re-submit the form, and watch for the request to show up in that tab. When it does, click it, and then click the *Response* or *Preview* tab to the right. It should tell you exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated create.js with instance variable for comment and it works now.

```
<% unless @comment.errors.any? %>
$("ul.comments").append('<%= j render partial: "comments/comment", locals:{comment: @comment} %>')
$("#new_comment")[0].reset();
<% end %>
```